# The ball not shows in page with SurfaceView. Why?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to write a program that moving a ball on screen by SurfaceView and changing X param of drawCircle() method but the program not shows anything in screen, just shows a black page.

This is my code.

TestsSurface.java:

```
 public class TestSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

public TestSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread thread=new Thread();
    thread.start();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void drawing(Canvas canvas){
    drawingShape(canvas);
}
int x=100;
public void drawingShape(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, 100, 50, paint);
    x+=2;
}

public void run(){
    Canvas canvas;
    while(true){
        canvas=null;
        try{
            synchronized(surfaceHolder){
                canvas=getHolder().lockCanvas();
                drawing(canvas);
            }
        }finally{
            if(canvas!=null)
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TestSurface test=new TestSurface(this);
    setContentView(test);

}
}
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `surfaceHolder` is never set on the call to `synchronized()`

Consider adding:

```
surfaceHolder = getHolder();
```

...to your constructor.

EDIT AS PER COMMENT BELOW::

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    while(true){
      canvas=null;
      try{
        synchronized(surfaceHolder){
          canvas=getHolder().lockCanvas();
          drawing(canvas);
        }
      }finally{
        if(canvas!=null)
          getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
      }
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I add surfaceHolder=getHolder(); to my constructor but when i run the program, the program shows a black screen again.

Comment: @NiceNICE You should try putting a `Thread.Sleep()` call on that loop to make sure its not executing too fast. If it iterates faster than you can actually see it and puts x into the range larger than your screen it will look black.

Comment: I write Thread.sleep(1000) below drawing() call in run() method,but the program not run correct. I cut run() method and paste in new class, the new class extends Thread. Now the program run correct, but i want to know what is the problem? Why i write run() method in TestSurface class, the program not run? Thanks

Comment: @NiceNICE I suppose that would be because your `Thread thread = new Thread()` doesn't actually tell the code to look at the current class you're using as a thread. I've updated my answer to show how you'd have to do it if you don't want to use another class...